# Sending postdata via HTTPClient to a RESTful API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

This seems very basic it should be far simpler than what we're already doing, but I'm trying to POST some content to a webAPI controller. We are using a third party CRM tool that allows us to send a POST request after certain actions are done. Said CRM tool sends content in the body of the POST.

I have no idea what the content is, so I'm just capturing the data.

My web api controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("ActivateUserAccount")]
public HttpResponseMessage ActivateUserAccount([FromBody] string key)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,key);
}
```

To simulate a call from the POST, I am doing this:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                    {
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key", "value")
                    });
    var result = client.PostAsync("", content).Result;
    var resultContent = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    Console.WriteLine(resultContent);
}
```

My routing is this:

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{Action}/{id}"
            ,defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional
            }
        );
```

when I run the test method, it's not sending anything -- or at least the controller isn't getting anything.

The Web API Controller is accessed via HTTPS, not sure if that's relevant (no 404s)

What am I missing?

EDIT: Changed routing pasted code.

Comment: the route you're show is a MVC route and not a Web API route. Also, do you have a example of the Uri you're posting too

Comment: Have you used fiddler to see what is happening?  And as @cecilphillip said, you need to look at WebApiConfig.cs for the Web API routes.

Comment: yep. I pasted the wrong routing. I have no issues actually getting to the url/controller method, the "key" parameter is just empty when it gets to the controller method.

Comment: Uri I'm posting to is a normal HTTPS uri: https://[someip]/api/ActivateUserAccount

Comment: that Uri will not match that route. Assuming ActivateUserAccount is ment to match the action, you have no match for the controller portion of your route. Your Uri should look like this https://[someip]/api/[controller]/ActivateUserAccount

Comment: Ugh. so many typos yesterday. https://[someip]/api/account/ActivateUserAccount is where it's going. Again, there's no problem reaching the endpoint, it's just that I'm not getting anything on the body of the message. Checking out fiddler now. Thanks guys!